# Refresh Directive when search called

Tags: angularjs, api, angularjs-directive, response, partial-page-refresh

Please Check plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/aoGESy8pYAEIVErKr8QF?p=preview

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="search.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <search dir-name="list-view1"></search>
  <list-view1></list-view1>
  
  <search dir-name="list-view2"></search>
  <list-view2></list-view2>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
angular.module('plunker', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}


angular.module('plunker').directive('listView1', function(){
 
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'list-view1.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
    },
    
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      
    }
  };
});


angular.module('plunker').directive('listView2', function(){
 
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'list-view2.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [6,7,8,9,10];
    },
    
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      
    }
  };
});
```

we have 2 directive list-view1 and list-view2 and also we have search directive common for everywhere.

Now my requirement is when I click search of list-view1 the data of list-view1 should be update

Similarly for list-view2.

Scenario is on click of submit I have to make api call that will return me data. after receiving data I need to update list-view with new data from where call have made.

Any Idea would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind items on the html elements, the view shoud be updated automatically when the items are updated. For example,

You have a function in the controller like

```
$scope.search = function(){
  $scope.items = getNewItems();
}
```

and you attached this function to the search button, if you have something like that in the view

```
<button ng-click="search()">Search</button>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item}} </li>
</ul>
```

the items in the view will be updated when you press the search button.

Comment: I did not understand your solution can you do it in plnkr. That would be great help

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/HFglboQaCSl1J2uIeyKk?p=preview As you see here, when data changed the view updated automatically.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question properly. please read it it and try understanding scenario